# swift rotate animation around center

Tags: ios, swift

I have `imageView` like vinyl record. And I want to create rotate animation. But if I use this code my vinyl record not exactly rotate around center. In this animation my image a little bit shifts up and down. How to fix it?

```
func startRotateView(targetView: UIView, duration: Double = 3.0) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            targetView.transform = targetView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        }) { finished in
            self.startRotateView(targetView: targetView, duration: duration)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CGAffineTransform` instead of rotated

```
targetView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
```

Comment: it depends on duration ... after the duration it will stop